# Why computer science discipline has different publications requirements: conferences as well as journals

Tags: publications, computer-science

Why is it like in CS, people expect from you both kinds of publications: conferences as well as journals?
I read some articles which says some conference have low acceptance ratio and you should count them. On the other hand, in academics, people also ask about the journal publications, when you face an interview.
These requirements also vary from country to country and university to university.
How to keep balance of both when think of publishing papers in CS?
Also which one has more weight theoretical vs. practical research publications, when apply for a job?

Thanks.

Comment: Also see [Is the status of conference publications in Computer Science really absolutely unique?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40783/is-the-status-of-conference-publications-in-computer-science-really-absolutely-u) and the long list of related questions in that post. I believe these adequately address the issue of conference vs journal publication in CS. If, after reading those, you still have an unanswered question, please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: In particular, see [this external link](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/advice/conferences-vs-journals.html) cited in [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/44496/11365).